# Which is the best option to fetch data from Mongodb database?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Sorry for a general question. My situation looks so: i have mongodb database and 2 reactjs pages. In each page i want to fetch a different information from database.  Depending by your practice, which is the best way to fetch data from mongodb in a reactjs component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading up on the MERN stack - tons of guides available online via google and youtube.  The gist would be that a typical web application will consist of a few key components.  In this case:

1 - (React) The client page rendered to the user

2 - (Node + Express) The server which processes data, allows you to use endpoints to make changes to your application.  These endpoints make the necessary database queries.  You can use a database client to write these queries as JavaScript within your NodeJS endpoints.

3 - (MongoDB) Your database.

So for instance a typical CRUD app allows you to create, read, update, and delete.  Let's say you are looking at making a standard TODO list app.

You would need to make requests to these endpoints to perform these operations.

You could have a POST to /todo which would then insert a new document into your database.

You would need a way to read the information from the page... say a GET request to /todos to read all items.  Or also a GET request to /todo/:id to get a specific item.

You would need a way to update an existing item... say a PUT request to /todo/:id with the updates you want to take place.

Finally you would need a way to delete an item... a DELETE request to /todo/:id which would delete the item.

Each of these endpoints would make a request to insert / read / update / delete items from the database, and return content to the client React code --> which then displays it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Frontend side, in react.js call api data using fetch() method. Pass your Mongodb URI string. If you want data in slot based use limit() and Skip() function for pagination. 
Follow MVC pattern where your frontend only calla controller api. And controller calls DAO methods for Mongodb. You can Use Mongodb Stitch for serverless app.sor data leak can be avoided forntend side. Mongodb has connecting pool max.100 so that each time client request Mongodb connection cashed object given from pool to further speed up your connection time.